# Why does Travis CI report a build success even though the npm publish failed?

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, npm-publish

I noticed on build https://travis-ci.org/neverendingqs/openssl-self-signed-certificate/builds/187723295 that I forgot to increase the patch version when tagging the repo. However, the build reported as `passing` even though the npm publish failed due to the version already existing.

Here's the tail end of the log:

```
Deploying application
NPM API key format changed recently. If your deployment fails, check your API key in ~/.npmrc.
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/
~/.npmrc size: 48
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.12-040812-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.48/bin/node" "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.48/bin/npm" "publish"
npm ERR! node v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! "You cannot publish over the previously published version 1.1.5." : openssl-self-signed-certificate
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/openssl-self-signed-certificate/npm-debug.log
No stash found.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

In case it's important, I have the `test` script in `packages.json` set to `exit 0`, but that occurs before the publish phase, so that shouldn't be the problem(?).

Why didn't Travis CI report the build a failure when the publish failed?

EDIT:

I used the Travis CI CLI to set up NPM publishing by running `travis setup npm`, based on https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/.

My `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: node_js
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: myemail
  api_key:
    secure: blahblahblah
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: neverendingqs/openssl-self-signed-certificate
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script must have exited with an exit status of 0.
This is the only thing that Travis cares about.

If you are running a script that does:

```
npm publish
```

Then it should do:

```
npm publish || exit 1
```

or something like that, to make sure that the script with that command exits with a non-zero status if the `npm publish` command fails.

You didn't include any example of your code but this is what I suspect may be happening here.

Actually it's even more complicated that that.
Let's say that you have one script, `script1` that fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

And you have another script, `script2` that runs it:

```
#!/bin/sh
./script1
```

then running `./script2` will also result in error - running this:

```
./script2 && echo OK || echo ERROR
```

will print ERROR. But when you have another command later:

```
#!/bin/sh
./script1
echo
```

then running `./script2` this time will not return error this time. Running:

```
./script2 && echo OK || echo ERROR
```

will print OK.

So if your `npm publish` is the last command in your script then it should result in the entire script returning an error status to the system, but if it's not then the system will get a status of 0 meaning success.

It all depends on how the script that Travis is running actually looks like.

Comment: I have updated the question with how I generated the `.travis.yml` content.

Comment: @rsp, thanks from 2018! This turned out to be very useful to me. In my setup `(create-react-app + custom .travis.yml)` I have been running `npm test -- --flags` and piping the output into `coveralls` through `| coveralls` which kept returning exit code `0` no matter what!

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is that Travis CI does not check the exit status from the `npm publish` command.

https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/blob/a255a0d8efe897f8ea5a194a8a2ef73556e27817/lib/dpl/provider/npm.rb#L35

This is currently a general problem with the deployment. See https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/143

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a different problem as we had some of our packaging and minification scripts located in the `after_success` section and even concatenating the commands did not fail the build until I later found out this was by design.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Breaking-the-Build

*"If any of the commands in the first four stages of the build lifecycle return a non-zero exit code, the build is broken:
If `before_install`, install or `before_script` return a non-zero exit code, the build is errored and stops immediately.
If `script` returns a non-zero exit code, the build is failed, but continues to run before being marked as failed.
**The exit code of** `after_success`, `after_failure`, `after_script` **and subsequent stages do not affect the build result.** However, if one of these stages times out, the build is marked as a failure."*

So I moved those commands to `install` and non-zero exit codes did start failing the build.